# How to Integrate Zxing api with Rhodes?

Tags: android, zxing, rhodes, pdf417

I'm working on a project which will to scan pdf417 barcodes, am developing this application using Rhodes specially for Android and iPhone. As I came to know that Zxing is one the useful api to scan pdf417 barcode for Android.

Can we Integrate Zxing with Rhodes ?
What is the procedure? 
Please let me know if anyone gone through this.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes uses Zxing in its Barcode class (http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.0.38/api/barcode), so there is support out of the box for some of Zxings features. For example for QR Codes and Code128 it works right away. However, not all types of Barcodes are supported on all platforms, so you should try out if pdf417 is supported on Android and IOS.

If it is not you can still write a native extension. It's actually not that hard. The documentation is relatively good (http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.0.38/guide/native_extensions). However, in my opinion it misses how to start and return to activities (via startActivity or startActivityForResult). But luckily the source code of how they implemented the Barcode class is open (https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/3-5-stable/lib/extensions/barcode/ext/barcode/platform/android/src/com/rhomobile/barcode/Barcode.java) so you can take it as a basis for your own native extension with a scanning engine which supports pdf417.